# Current detection at a distance

Tags: current, proximity-sensor

I am trying to determine the feasibility of detecting a cable on the outside of an oilwell casing pipe.  The sensor would be run inside this pipe and the pipe is approximately 1/4" thick.  The cable could be as far as 2 inches from the pipe.

If I applied a current to the cable, is there a sensor that could pick up the current?

The cable, could be 20,000 ft long. Is this possible with today's technology?  What would be my major challenges?

Comment: What's an oilwell casing pipe made of?

Comment: Detecting anything through 1/4" steel would be quite a challenge indeed...

Comment: How much current are we talking here?

Comment: To answer the additional questions:  Casing pipe is usually a 4140 steel and material is ferrous.  One conductor we are considering is 18 gauge copper, so current may be limited, especially 20,000 ft of length.

Answer (score 2):

Probably possible. You can use a low frequency (maybe 1Hz) AC and synchronously demodulate it. The wires in the cable will be some distance apart so there should be some signal available outside the pipe. The thicker the pipe the lower the frequency that you should use (skin depth of steel at 1Hz is about 10mm).

Major challenge- SNR and asymmetric signal- perhaps requiring 2 or more pickups.